# content searching by custom taxonomies in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, taxonomy

I made some custom taxonomies in my wordpress site and now I want to search the particular taxonomy related content and display these by selecting the taxonomies option from drop down list.

Suppose One of my taxonomies name is "`metal`". then I made this as drop down by following code:

```
wp_dropdown_categories( 'taxonomy=metal' );
```

But I don't know how to search the related content in my site by selecting metal list from drop down bar. Is there any appropriate solution or plugin for that?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is it that you try to achieve? Do you want to limit your search to the selected term or just display everything that has this term?

Answer (score 1):

**Try the below code.It worked for me:**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
        <?php $arr = array('taxonomy'=> 'metal','hierarchical' => 'true','show_count' => 'true','hide_empty'=> '0', 'selected' =>  $kat = get_query_var( 'cat' ), 'name' => 'cat', 'id' => '', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'echo' => 0); ?>

        <div class="dep_list">
            <label>Select a department:</label><?php $select = wp_dropdown_categories($arr); ?>
            <?php $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select);
            echo $select; ?>
        </div>
</form>

<?php
  $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'your post type slug',
   'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'metal', 'terms' => array($kat), 'field' => 'id') ) );

   $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
   echo '<div class="row">';
   if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            <h4><?php echo the_title(); ?></h4>
            <p><?php echo the_content(); ?></p>

    </div>

  <?php endwhile;
}?>
```